# accessing first element in js collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my js function I had following

```
success: function (result) {
     $.each(result, function (i, item) {                  
        $("#tab-" + item.myType).append(result);
     })
}
```

Now I've change this function and instead I have following

```
success: function (result) {
   $("#tab-how To Access to the first result collection element ").html(result);
 }
}
```

I tried with

```
$("#tab-" + result[0].item.myType).html(result);
```

but it didn't help.

Question is: How to access to the first js element inside result collection object

Any thoughts ?

Using console.log(result) I'm getting html snippets which I display on partial view

```
div class="product clearfix">
        <div class="l-new">
            <a href="#">
                @Model.MyType (rendered as My Type)
            </a> 
....
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide an example of how `result` looks like. :)

Comment: We have no idea what `result` looks like unless you post the structure. `console.log` the data and paste the output here. If it's a huge object you can abbreviate it

Comment: Please do `console.log(result)` inside the success and post it...

Comment: @Palash on console.log(result) I'm getting html snippets, so I guess I cannot use result[0].MyType to render proper div id.

Comment: So, you want the first link `a` text??

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
result[0] // if you have numeric indices in your result collection
```

OR

```
var firstItem = null;
for(var x in result) { // if you have named properties
    firstItem = result[x];
    break;
}
```